# Query on c++ iterator tag

Tags: c++

I was going through a code snippet

```
template <class RAIter>
void alg(RAIter, RAIter, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    std::cout << "alg() called for random-access iterator\n";
}
```

For the first time, I am seeing only the data types in the function parameter section (std::random_access_iterator_tag). I am used to seeing

[std::random_access_iterator_tag rand_iter;]

This sort of representation is allowed in templates but not in non-templated functions.

Two questions:

1) Why is only data type name mentioned but no variable of it is mentioned?

2) Why is it allowed only for templated functions but not for non-templated functions?

Comment: You can have unnamed arguments for any functions.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that non-template functions can't have unnamed parameters?

Comment: A left-over from the ancient days of pre-ANSI C, is it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that's not related to templates at all.

It's an unnamed parameter and it's perfectly legal when:

- declaring a method (so you have no body)
- defining a method that won't use that argument

Basically you can respect a signature without having a named argument at all costs, eg:

```
float foo(float, int, float);

int main()
{
  float x = foo(10.0f, 5, 20.0f);
  return 0;
}

float foo(float a, int, float b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

This can be useful in some specific circumstances, think about pure `virtual` methods or forward declaration of methods.

In a specific case it helps to suppress the **unused parameter** warning, for example:

```
float foo(float a, int z, float b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

This yields a warning with `-Wunused-parameter` but won't if you explicitly state that you won't use it by removing its name.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Why is only data type name mentioned but no variable of it is mentioned?

Because the parameter is not used, so the name is not needed.

> 2) Why is it allowed only for templated functions but not for non-templated functions?

Actually it *is* allowed on non-templated functions as well.